# Why Bootstrap panel is not working in Blazor client?

Tags: razor, .net-core, blazor

I compile below code to get a bootstrap panel but no success

[image]

```
@page "/test"
<h3>test</h3>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-primary class</div>
    <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
</div>

@code {

}
```

the project setting is
[image]

And bootstrap.main.cs is

[image]

The wwwroot folder looks like this

[image]

Index.html

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blazor uses Bootstrap 4 and there `.panel` [was replaced](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#panels-thumbnails-and-wells) by `.card`

So the basic version becomes this:

```
<div class="card text-primary">
    <div class="card-header">Panel with panel-primary class</div>
    <div class="card-body">Panel Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

add in Index.html Head section

```
<link href="Bootstrap/bootstrap.mini.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```